# Can Someone Tell Me Why My Projectiles Arent Showing Up On My Screen Test Shows The Projectiles are firing doesnt display on my screen?

Tags: python, pygame

on my output idle its printing that the bullets are [firing](https://gyazo.com/abd3a95375d560d6f36159e7e3e8a28a) but they arent showing up on my screen

```
    if len(bulls):
        bull = Bullet(round(smallice1.x+dir_x), round(smallice1.y+dir_y))
        bulls.append(bull)
    if round(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000) % 3 == 0:
        print("shooting")
    if bulls != []:                                                                   #Firing bullets
        for bull in bulls:
            bulls.append(bull)
        if bull.y < 400:                                         #Bullet movement
            bull.x += bull.v
        else:
            bulls.pop(bulls.index(bull))                                      #Poping bullets from list

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

the bullets class

```
# enemys bullets
class Bullet:
  def __init__(self, x, y, bull_x, bull_y, color):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.dirx = bull_x
      self.diry = bull_y
      self.slash = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
      self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
      self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
      self.speed = 10
      self.color = color
  def move(self):
      self.x += self.bull_x * self.speed
      self.y += self.bull_y * self.speed
  def draw(self, window):
      self.rect.topleft = (round(self.x), round(self.y))
      window.blit(self.slash,self.rect)
```

even tho i rain this function below

```
   for bull in bulls:
       bull.draw(window)
```

full code
https://pastebin.com/EN6pU7bR

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're trying to do... why are you adding every bullet that's already in the bullets to the bullets list again, and why are you only adding a bullet when there are no bullets?

Comment: I am trying to make something shoot out projectiles just like how I did it for the  player but without clicking

Answer (score 0):

I redone my bullet class

```
class Bullet(object):
   def __init__(self, x, y,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.slash = pygame.image.load("littleboy.png")
       self.rect  = self.slash.get_rect()
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x, self.y )
       self.speed = 10
       self.color = color

   def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = ( self.x,self.y )
       window.blit(slash, self.rect)
```

and shorten the firing part for the player  added a variable list outside of my main loop called bulls = [] then used that I am bad at explainging things the 
code is simple I can you can read it

```
for bull in bulls:
    if bull.x < 500 and bull.x > 0:
        bull.x += bull.speed
    else:
        bulls.pop(bulls.index(bull))
if len(bulls) < 2:
        bulls.append(Bullet(round(smallice1.x+smallice1.width//2),round(smallice1.y + smallice1.height-60),(0,0,0)))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate for people finding this in the future?